# Updating data using custom field in Odoo External API

Tags: odoo, updates, odoo-12

Currently, I am working with external API and would like to know, is it possible to update the orders not by defining Odooid, but by defining custom id.

I have `x_customer_id` field and I want to give this as a parameter for updating. Is it somehow possible?

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'write', [[id], {
    'name': "Newer partner"
}])
```

Instead of `[[id]]`, to write `x_customer_id`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to search for all records where x_customer_id meets your requirements. so use "search" term instead of "write" at first and then you have all id´s you need to write your values to.